# Copy some text from the site to Excel (Run-time error 462)

Tags: vba, selectors-api

The program works (needed  text displayed in Excel). But after that IE stops working and Run-time error 462  (The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable) . Searching solution in the internet.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510 .
I can not effectively change the code .

```
   Sub extractTablesData1()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Data As Object
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim elemCollection As Variant

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks("IESite.xlsx")
Set xlsh = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate ("http://allscores.ru/soccer/new_ftour.php?champ=2404&f_team=406&tour=110")
    While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set Data = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("table")(6).querySelectorAll("td.clr, td.clr_win, td.clr_draw, td.clr_loose")
    i = 1
    For Each elemCollection In Data
        xlsh.Cells(34, 1 + i).Value = elemCollection.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next elemCollection
End With
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

As described in the link:

> RESOLUTION
>   To resolve this problem, modify the code so each call to an Excel object, method, or property is qualified with the appropriate object variable.

You are using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(34, 1 + i).Value
```

This should be:

```
Dim xlwb as Workbook
Dim xlsh as Worksheet

set xlwb = Workbooks("IESite")
set xlsh = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")

xlsh.Cells(34, 1 + i).Value = elemCollection.innerText
```

Further changes:

As required by the solution, everything needs to be defined. Let me know if with the below way it does work, if so i'll remove the code above.

Don't forget to **define** `ElemCollection`

```
Sub extractTablesData1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Data As Object
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim elemCollection as ... 'please define elemCollection as the type it is

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks("IESite.xlsx")
    Set xlsh = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate ("http://allscores.ru/soccer/new_ftour.php?champ=2404&f_team=406&tour=110")
        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set Data = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("table")(6).querySelectorAll("td.clr, td.clr_win, td.clr_draw, td.clr_loose")
        i = 1
        For Each elemCollection In Data
            xlsh.Cells(34, 1 + i).Value = elemCollection.innerText
            i = i + 1
        Next elemCollection
    End With
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the code, and then I got  Run-time error 9 (Subscript out of range)

Comment: did you change the naming of the `Workbook` and `Worksheet`?

Comment: I changed names , then we back to the original problem (IE stops working and Run-time error 462)

Comment: elemCollection As Variant ,but then i got Run-time error 9

Comment: @maxim465 names were altered? and grab the code again just saw I typed `xlbook` by accident instead of `xlwb`

Comment: see update . Names were not altered. I got Run-time error 9 again.

Comment: Still error 9 with correct workbook and worksheet name?